# Keep files on working tree but make them available to any branch?

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-submodules

I'd like to have a few files of code available to any branch, but keep those files on their own branch (rather, "branch", since this might not be possible with branches). Is there a better way to do this than putting the code in another repository and adding a submodule? I'd like to keep the code in the same repository.

For context: It's a server for testing the dev branch that I don't want to put on master or on the dev branch (which I later want to merge into master, without the test server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want some code to be available for all branches but not committed, then you could simply have it as set of untracked files. 
In all other scenarios you would need to either change your workflow and do some shaman dances rebasing, cherry-picking or use submodules.

My general opinion though is that you should have the test server in a separate repository and tune it up so it can get the code of your project straight from you main project repo, for example as compiled artifact (jar, or source or whatever) and then you don't need any submodules or anything else. I'm pretty sure that the test server code can be tuned that way. You're not polluting the project code with the test server code - they are decoupled and can exists in the world without affecting each other.

Hope that helps!